# Simulate key presses with Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

We've defined the key-press sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in our web application to a specific action (save the current form).

Now we want to test that behavior with Robot Framework. How can we describe that accurately to do that?

The documentation describes how to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> or any single key press, but nothing is said about combinations. So how to trigger a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, for instance?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same and came across this. It says it is under implementation. Follow this for more update.

https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/498

Lets hope it will be available to use by Oct-2015.

Comment: Unfortunately, issue is still opened - [Press Keys in Robot framework](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/498)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with the ImageHorizonLibrary:

http://eficode.github.io/robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary/doc/ImageHorizonLibrary.html#Press%20Combination

```
Press Combination    Key.CTRL    Key.S
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys) in the documentation you have examples of multiple keys pressed :

```
Press Keys  locator CTRL+S
```